# Can't replace char in string

Tags: python, string, replace

The first char of string `tmp_el[1]` always is `'^'`
and i need to remove it.

I am using `.replace('^', '')` but nothing happend.

[image: Debug Image]

Comment: Don't include your code as an image. Include the actual text instead.

Comment: do not post screenshots of code to this site please.  Code is written in plain text; SO questions should be too.

Comment: Strings are immutable, `.replace(..)` creates a *new* string with the modificaiton.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`replace` [returns a *copy* of the string](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) in which the replacement has taken place. In your code, you discard the result of `.replace()`. The value in the array is never updated. You could solve this via:

```
tmp_el[1] = tmp_el[1].replace('^', '')
```